# Unable to sideload UWP app from app package

Tags: uwp, packaging, sideloading

I am trying to side load an app that I developed on the same computer. I am following these instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx . It says that when a package is created there should be the following folders:

> C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\AppPackages\MyApp_1.0.2.0_x64
> C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\AppPackages\MyApp_1.0.2.0_x64_Test

But only the test folder is created. When the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file is Run with PowerShell, there is the following error:

> Installing app...
>
> Found dependency package(s):
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Dtapp\Dtapp\AppPackages\Dtapp_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Dtapp\Dtapp\AppPackages\Dtapp_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Dtapp\Dtapp\AppPackages\Dtapp_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx
>
> C:\Users\Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Dtapp\Dtapp\AppPackages\Dtapp_1.0.0.0_Debug_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx
>
> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed.
>
> Please contact your software vendor.
>
> Unspecified error

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the developer mode on?

Comment: Yes developer mode is enabled.

Comment: go to group policy and enable "Allow all trusted apps to install". Not sure but may be this can help. Also try disabling your antivirus and then install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to sideload the app after uninstalling it from the start menu/all apps.

Comment: I was having the same problem with another app. Your solution worked. I didn't know that running a program with the debugger is the same as installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check are folders C:\Windows\AUInstallAgent and C:\Windows\AppReadiness present in your system. If not, create a blank folders and reboot your PC.
That's the usual solution for 0x80073CF9 error

Comment: C:\Windows\AppReadiness was there, and I created C:\Windows\AUInstallAgent, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: you can also try to recover all store apps like it's written [here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-reinstall-all-windows-10-default-apps-powershell)

Comment: It did not work. I restored Windows 10 and that worked. Not sure what was interfering with sideloading.